# I helped friend on exam by writing answers in large font size, and didn't erase it properly. Will I get into trouble?

Tags: exams, cheating

The answer contained 4 words, I wrote them in a large font size.

I erased them at the last minute, but it's still visible if you see it closely. Can lecturer accuse me of cheating in this case?

Comment: Downvoters really need to understand that voting is for the *quality of the question itself* rather than whether they dislike/disagree with its context or the OP's behavior.

Comment: I downvote because this is a terrible question. 'i cheated and tried to destroy potential evidence but didn't do it perfectly, does it still count as evidence of cheating?" You don't need to be studying at university to work out the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on two things. First if you get caught, and then second on the academic misconduct policy of your class/department/school/university/... As for getting caught, eraser marks of large text seems like a pretty obvious example of attempted cheating. I would expect most graders to see these marks and want to follow up. As for academic misconduct policies, most of the policies I have seen include helping another student gain an unfair advantage as academic misconduct. Some policies include additional penalties for trying to cover up academic misconduct (i.e., erasing the large text).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this will get closed, but you can be *accused* of anything. Due process will dictate whether the accusation holds water, however. All you can do is wait and see.

Comment: This is basically the answer. The OP **is** guilty of cheating, and I would not hesitate to make an issue of it on a final, but might not go to so much trouble if it's a small quiz.